# Command to follow Server supply

Tags: shell, unix, command, debian

I would like to know if there is a Shell command to follow the supply voltage & current of a Linux PC ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the lm-sensors package. `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors` Then you can use the `sensors` command.

More info here: http://www.lm-sensors.org/

Comment: and if you want to *follow* the values use `watch sensors`